# Heatmap-like plot for three categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I'm dealing with a data frame of categorical variables in case form, made up of three variables (i.e. color, shape and size) and its corresponding frequency. An example of the data frame is like this:

```
 Color    Shape     Size   Freq
1 Yellow  Square    Big    10
2 Yellow  Square    Medium  6
3 Yellow  Square    Small   3
4 Yellow  Triangle  Big     4
5 Yellow  Triangle  Medium  6
6 Yellow  Triangle  Small   8
7 Red     Square    Big     2
8 Red     Square    Medium  6
9 Red     Square    Small   5
10Red     Triangle  Big    12
.......
```

The "color" variable is measured against the "shape" and "size" variables, having a frequency for each case.

From this data frame I'm struggling to create a heatmap-like plot where only the relation between "Color" and "Shape" is displayed, and using as weight the variable "Size" with the highest frequency. Bit tricky, isn't it!

For example, for the "Yellow" - "Square" cases I should only display "Big", since "big" is the size with the highest freq. For every size there should be an accompanying color (i.e "red" for big, "green" for medium, and "orange" for small).
Frank

Comment: can you give the results of dput(your data frame)..Also, what do you want to do in cases where there is a tie in frequency between sizes?

Comment: dput seems too long to show here, I copy str(df) if it helps. Regarding the case of tie, always choose the higher in frequency. `str(df)
data.frame: 750 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Id             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Constraint     : Factor w/ 10 levels "Biz-demand","Capacity",..: 8 8 8 8 8 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ ValueRepository: Factor w/ 15 levels "Alliances","Brand",..: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ Strength       : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "VS"<"S"<"W"<"VW"<..: 5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 ...
 $ Freq           : int  1 1 0 6 5 3 1 0 6 3 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_max <- df %>%
  group_by(Color, Shape) %>%
  slice(which.max(Freq))

head(df_max)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: Color, Shape [4]
# 
#    Color    Shape   Size  Freq
#    (chr)    (chr)  (chr) (int)
# 1    Red   Square Medium     6
# 2    Red Triangle    Big    12
# 3 Yellow   Square    Big    10
# 4 Yellow Triangle  Small     8

ggplot(df_max, aes(x = Color, y = Shape, fill = Size)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty close to what I needed! Please let me add two more considerations: (1) how to solve freq tie cases (i.e. always higher size is preferred), and (2) how to rearrange axes to reflect colors as grouped as possible (i.e. those with Strength "big"= red, as close as possible). Thanks for your great help! Frank

Comment: @Frank The easiest way to solve #1 would be to sort the Sizes before slicing (that is, add `arrange(Size)` before `slice(which.max(Freq))`. For #2, it's not clear what you are asking, but I am guessing that this could be solved by rearranging and sorting the resulting data frame. It might be best to ask these as a separate question(s).