# Plotting three dimensions of categorical data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My data has three categorical variables I'm trying to visualize:

- City (one of five)
- Occupation (one of four)
- Blood type (one of four)

So far, I've succeeded in grouping the data in a way that I think will be easy to work with:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

# Make data
cities = ['Tijuana','Las Vegas','Los Angeles','Anaheim','Atlantis']
occupations = ['Doctor','Lawyer','Engineer','Drone security officer']
bloodtypes = ['A','B','AB','O']
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': np.random.choice(cities,500),
                   'Occupation': np.random.choice(occupations,500),
                   'Blood Type':np.random.choice(bloodtypes,500)})

# You need to make a dummy column, otherwise the groupby returns an empty df
df['Dummy'] = np.ones(500)

# This is now what I'd like to plot
df.groupby(by=['City','Occupation','Blood Type']).count().unstack(level=1)
```

Returns:

```
                       Dummy
Occupation             Doctor Drone security officer Engineer Lawyer
City        Blood Type
Anaheim     A               7                      7        7      7
            AB              6                     10        8      5
            B               2                     10        4      2
            O               4                      3        3      6
Atlantis    A               6                      5        5      7
            AB             12                      7        7     10
            B               7                      4        7      3
            O               7                      4        6      4
Las Vegas   A               8                      4        8      5
            AB              5                      6        8      9
            B               6                     10        6      6
            O               6                      9        5      9
Los Angeles A               7                      4        8      8
            AB              9                      8        8      8
            B               3                      6        4      1
            O               9                     11       11      9
Tijuana     A               3                      4        5      3
            AB              9                      5        5      7
            B               3                      6        4      9
            O               3                      5        5      8
```

My goal is to create something like the Seaborn swarmplot shown below, which comes from the [Seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html). Seaborn applies jitter to the quantitative data so that you can see the individual data points and their hues:

[image: sns example]

With my data, I'd like to plot `City` on the x-axis and `Occupation` on the y-axis, applying jitter to each, and then hue by `Blood type`. However, `sns.swarmplot` **requires one of the axes to be quantitative**:

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df,x='City',y='Occupation',hue='Blood Type')
```

returns an error.

**An acceptable alternative** might be to create 20 categorical bar plots, one for each intersection of `City` and `Occupation`, which I would do by running a for loop over each category, but I can't imagine how I'd feed that to matplotlib subplots to get them in a 4x5 grid.

The [most similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851208/heatmap-like-plot-for-three-categorical-variables) I could find was in R, and the asker only wanted to indicate the most common value for the third variable, so I didn't get any good ideas from there.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I got to work on the "acceptable alternative" today and I have found a solution using basically pure matplotlib (but I stuck the Seaborn styling on top of it, just because).

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import seaborn as sns

# Make data
cities = ['Tijuana','Las Vegas','Los Angeles','Anaheim','Atlantis']
occupations = ['Doctor','Lawyer','Engineer','Drone security officer']
bloodtypes = ['A','B','AB','O']
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': np.random.choice(cities,500),
                   'Occupation': np.random.choice(occupations,500),
                   'Blood Type':np.random.choice(bloodtypes,500)})

# Make a dummy column, otherwise the groupby returns an empty df
df['Dummy'] = np.ones(500)

# This is now what I'd like to plot
grouped = df.groupby(by=['City','Occupation','Blood Type']).count().unstack()

# List of blood types, to use later as categories in subplots
kinds = grouped.columns.levels[1]

# colors for bar graph
colors = [get_cmap('viridis')(v) for v in np.linspace(0,1,len(kinds))]

sns.set(context="talk")
nxplots = len(grouped.index.levels[0])
nyplots = len(grouped.index.levels[1])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nxplots,
                         nyplots,
                         sharey=True,
                         sharex=True,
                         figsize=(10,12))

fig.suptitle('City, occupation, and blood type')

# plot the data
for a, b in enumerate(grouped.index.levels[0]):
    for i, j in enumerate(grouped.index.levels[1]):
        axes[a,i].bar(kinds,grouped.loc[b,j],color=colors)
        axes[a,i].xaxis.set_ticks([])

axeslabels = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.grid(False)
axeslabels.set_ylabel('City',rotation='horizontal',y=1,weight="bold")
axeslabels.set_xlabel('Occupation',weight="bold")

# x- and y-axis labels
for i, j in enumerate(grouped.index.levels[1]):
    axes[nyplots,i].set_xlabel(j)
for i, j in enumerate(grouped.index.levels[0]):
    axes[i,0].set_ylabel(j)

# Tune this manually to make room for the legend
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.82)

fig.legend([Patch(facecolor = i) for i in colors],
           kinds,
           title="Blood type",
           loc="center right")
```

Returns this:
[image: subplot barplots]

I'd appreciate any feedback, and I'd still love it if someone could provide the preferred solution.