# How can i plotting two columns with string as value in a DataSet with Matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataset

I have the following Dataset and I wanna create a plot, which to columns compares with each other.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ds=pd.read_csv('h-t-t-p-:bit.ly/uforeports') #My DataSet
ds.head(5) # Only the fist 5 rows to show

ds1= ds.head(4).drop(['Colors Reported','State'],axis=1) # Droping of unnecesssary rows
print(ds1)
```

Now I wanna compare "City" and "Shape Reported" with help of plotting. I found something with Pandas but this is not so elegant!

```
x=ds.loc[0:100,['State']]
y=ds.loc[0:100,['Shape Reported']]

x.apply(pd.value_counts).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)
y.apply(pd.value_counts).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)
```

Do you know a better solution with **Matplotlib** to this problem?

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpjN0.png)

Comment: Have you tried looking at any tutorials for Matplotlib? Many of them walk you through this exactly. Consider looking at [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm)

Comment: Yes i have. But if u see exactly this tutorial, it explains only the comprehension between numbers and texts. I wanna a comprehension between text and text!

Comment: I know that it will simple with Sklearn.compose and ColumnTrasnform but I wanna do it with python

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303175/plotting-three-dimensions-of-categorical-data-in-python

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear how you want to compare them.

The simplest way of drawing a bar chart is:

```
df['State'].value_counts().plot.bar()
df['Shape Reported'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

If you just want to do it for the first 100 rows as in your example, just add `head(100)`:

```
df['State'].head(100).value_counts().plot.bar()
df['Shape Reported'].head(100).value_counts().plot.bar()
```

EDIT:

To compare the two values you can plot a bivariate distribution plot. This is easily done with seaborn:

```
import seaborn
sns.displot(df,x='State', y='Shape Reported', height=6, aspect=1.33)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: my intention is only, that I  wanna compare the values of column 'State' as X-Axis the values in columns ''Shape Reported' as Y-Axis.

Comment: unfortunately is not what I want

Comment: can you provide an example of the style of plot you want?

Comment: @ mullinscr
I've edited my question. The link of figure you can find in my question